# can't import nearest neighbors in scikit-learn 0.16

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
'0.16.1'
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .graph import kneighbors_graph, radius_neighbors_graph   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/graph.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .base import KNeighborsMixin, RadiusNeighborsMixin   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..metrics import pairwise_distances   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .classification import accuracy_score   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, label_binarize   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ._weights import balance_weights ImportError: cannot import name 'balance_weights'
```

Comment: It looks like your sklearn is bust are you able to reinstall?

Comment: I will give it a try. I am using sklearn 0.14 with python2.7 with no problems.

Comment: how did you install?

Comment: I installed 0.16 again and everything is ok now. thanks