# Cannot import from sklearn import c

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on jupyter notebook on a python assignment and 
I am trying to import  **KNearestNeighbor** from **sklearn** but I am getting the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'KNearestNeighbor' from 'sklearn'
>   (C:\Users\michaelconway\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py)

I have checked and I do have sklearn installed: version 0.22

Any ideas please?

Comment: try to remove `sklearn` and reinstall it; you can refer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124375/cant-import-nearest-neighbors-in-scikit-learn-0-16

Comment: Please provide the code that resulted in this error.

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen `KNearestNeighbor` in sklearn. There is two thing you can do instead of `KNearestNeighbor`

1. `from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier`

   > or
2. `from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors`

I think 1st option is the option which you want now

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

If you are working on jupyter notebook on a python assignment and you are trying to import KNearestNeighbor from sklearn but you are getting an error: **IMPORT ERROR**
then try

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
```